# Kotlin lazy slice array

Tags: kotlin

I need to iterate part of an array backwards. I'd like to do that "functionally" as it's more comprehensible, like that

```
for (b in buf.sliceArray(0 until bufLimit).reversedArray()) {}
```

But both `sliceArray` and `reversedArray` are not lazy. Is there a lazy version or should I probably fall back to

```
for (bIdx in bufLimit - 1 downTo 0) {
    val b = buf[bIdx]
}
```

which is more confusing and verbose?

Comment: What about this? `buf.take(bufLimit).reversed().forEach { ... }`

Comment: @marstran `ByteArray.take` as well isn't lazy, it creates an `ArrayList`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you use a list instead of an array, then you can reverse it and then convert to a `Sequence`:

```
val buf: List = listOf(1, 2, 3, 4, 5)
val bufLimit = 3

for (b in buf.asReversed().asSequence().drop(buf.size - bufLimit)) {
    println(b)
}
```

Functions with the `as` prefix only wrap objects without copying, so the code above does not copy the `buf` content.

Note that you shouldn't loose any performance compared to `Array` if you use an `ArrayList`.

However this solution does involve several iterators, so it is somewhat less efficient than the index code you have suggested in the question:

```
for (bIdx in bufLimit - 1 downTo 0) {
    val b = buf[bIdx]
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I suggest creating an extension function to handle your specific use case. e.g.:

```
/**
 * Performs the given [action] on each element at the specified [indices].
 */
inline fun ByteArray.forEachAt(indices: Iterable<Int>, action: (Byte) -> Unit): Unit {
    indices.forEach { index -> action(this[index]) }
}
```

Usage:

```
buf.forEachAt((0 until bufLimit).reversed)) {}
// or
buf.forEachAt(bufLimit - 1 downTo 0) {}
```